# No DataContext found for binding TwoWay?

Tags: wpf

I have a usercontrol which has as a component

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
 <Grid Name="WeekViewGrid"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                   
  local:GridSetUp.WeekView="{Binding TheWeek.Days, Mode=TwoWay}"
  local:GridSetUp.GridData="{Binding TheGridData,  Mode=TwoWay}"
  IsSharedSizeScope="True">
 </Grid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

where GridSetup.WeekView and GridSetUp.GridData are two attached properties.

Intellisense underlines `TwoWay` and tells me "No DataContext found for binding TwoWay"
There doesn't seem to be any problem with the binding to TheWeek.Days, and TheGridData, both properties of the DataContext.

What's going on there? The Mode syntax is correct no? Why is it trying to make a binding expression out of the Mode property? If it's possibly relevant I could supply more code for the attached properties and the the datacontext's properties, but didn't want to clutter up at this point.
Edit: ok, here's more detail on the attached properties

```
public static  DependencyProperty WeekViewProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "WeekView", typeof(ObservableCollection<Day>), typeof(GridSetUp), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Day> { }, WeekViewChanged)); public static ObservableCollection<Day> GetWeekView(Grid grid)
 {
  return (ObservableCollection<Day>)grid.GetValue(WeekViewProperty);
 }
public static void SetWeekView(Grid grid, ObservableCollection<Day> value)
 {
            grid.SetValue(WeekViewProperty, value);
 }
```

and

```
public static  DependencyProperty GridDataProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
"GridData", typeof(GridData), typeof(GridSetUp), new PropertyMetadata(new GridData(), GridDataChanged));

public static GridData GetGridData(Grid grid)
 {
  return (GridData)grid.GetValue(GridDataProperty);
 }
  public static void SetGridData(Grid grid, GridData value)
 {
   grid.SetValue(GridDataProperty, value);
  }
  public static void GridDataChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {           
 }
```

Things are functioning as I expect, but I don't understand the intellisense advice. Is it just spurious and not a bother?

Comment: It's just the XAML designer complaining. You may assign a design-time DataContext.

Answer (score 3):

Assign a design-time Datacontext:

```
<Window x:Class="YourClass" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:YourViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        ETC...
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window>
```

The problem is design time only.
It means, the datacontext will not be known until you run the application.
But, you can assign a design-time datacontext, as shown in the example, to avoid this problem.

You can even use a different datacontext for design-time and runtime. A simple design-time datacontext may be conveniently populated to see the effect on the UI.